# try and catch in C++ - how many objects are created

Tags: c++, c++11, try-catch

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Box{
    public: 
        std::string show(){
            std::cout<<"Box show executed"<<std::endl;
            return "msg";
        };

        ~Box(){
            std::cout<<"Box destructor is executed"<<std::endl;
        };
};

int main(){

    try{
        Box obj;
        std::cout<<"Coming here"<<std::endl;
        throw obj;
    }
    catch(Box msg){
        std::cout<<"I have caught the exception: \n"<<msg.show()<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

In GCC compiler the output is:

```
Coming here
Box destructor is executed
Box show executed
I have caught the exception:
msg
Box destructor is executed
Box destructor is executed
```

My confusions are:

1. The statement prints are very confusing, why is the "Box show
   executed" printing before the "I have caught the exception" line?
2. There are three destructors called, How is this possible when only
       two objects are created, one the Box object in the try and the temp
       object in the try which is passed to the catch block?

Comment: You are not tracing the copy constructor and default constructor of `Box`.  Do that and you will see where the objects are coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The statement prints are very confusing, why is the "Box show executed" printing before the "I have caught the exception" line?

The order of evaluation of function/operator arguments is unspecified. Your code is equivalent to this below:

```
operator<<(operator<<((std::cout << "I have caught the exception: \n"), msg.show()), std::endl);
```

Which of the two below is executed first is undefined:

```
std::cout << "I have caught the exception: \n"
msg.show() // i.e. std::cout << "Box show executed" << std::endl;
```

In your case `msg.show()` is evaluated before the first `operator <<` is called. A different compiler may produce code with these calls in a different order.

> There are three destructors called, How is this possible when only two objects are created, one the Box object in the try and the temp object in the try which is passed to the catch block?

When you throw a local object by value:

1. It is copied to a special reserved memory for exceptions.
2. Original object is destroyed (1).
3. Exception handler should be found and the object is copied from a special reserved memory to an exception handler stack.
4. A copied object is removed from a special memory (2).
5. When an Exception handler exited, an object is removed from its stack (3).

Comment: @ S.M. How is it undefined?

Comment: @Jarod42 , is it really undefined behaviour?

Comment: @niceboy-programmer It seems you like to cling to words. Unspecified evaluation order means the order of evaluation is undefined.

Comment: @S.M. I meant how? Is it mentioned somewhere? And the reason for it? The << operator is evaluated from left to right, right?

Comment: Right. But you have another inner expression `msg.show()`. Compiler evaluated it before the first `<<`. It may evaluate `cout.operator<<("I have caught the exception: \n")`, `msg.show()` and `cout.operator<<("msg")`. Or  may `msg.show()`, `cout.operator<<("I have caught the exception: \n")` and `cout.operator<<("msg")`. Order for evaluation of `msg.show()` between operators `<<` is unspecified.

Comment: @S.M. But that is horrible, I have always been using that. Like returning values from function during printing with the << operators. Is this a not good practise? For example, evaluating a volume with `std::cout<<"The volume is: "<<something.volume()<<"m^3<<std::endl;`  ?

Comment: It is not horrible. Evaluation order of the inner expressions is not important in your last code, since the inner expressions are invariant to `cout`. So it is a good practice. The code in the question is conceptually different. There `msg.show()` changes `cout` state. You can see there that returned value "msg" of inner expression `msg.show()` is placed in right order of the output.

Comment: @S.M. Please tell me what it means to change state of `cout`? They basically print to output stream right? What's the difference between printing an int and a string?

Comment: Think about `int a = 0; a = a + ++a;`. You can get `a` is 1 or 2.  `operator +` here is more intuitive than `operator <<`, but it has the same behavior.

Comment: The expansion provided is not true. There is no overload for `ostream::operator<<()` that accepts `std::string` as input. So the free function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&)` will be used.

Comment: @E.Vakili m which expansion is not true?

Comment: @niceboy-programmer In `cout.operator<<("I have caught the exception: \n").operator<<(msg.show()).operator<<(std::endl);`

Answer (score 0):

> why is the "Box show executed" printing before the "I have caught the
>   exception" line?

Because it wants to evaluate `show()` method in `catch` section, it will print string first.

> There are three destructors called

Because you are catching `Box` normally, if you use `Box&` you will see only 2 calls to destructor. In your code, object is copied twice and with 1 main object, you need 3 destructor calls. If you change your code as following, you see these copy constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Box{
    public: 
        Box(){}
        Box(const Box &obj){
            std::cout <<"copy"<<std::endl;
        }

        std::string show(){
            std::cout<<"Box show executed"<<std::endl;
            return "msg";
        };

        ~Box(){
            std::cout<<"Box destructor is executed"<<std::endl;
        };
};

int main(){

    try{
        Box obj;
        std::cout<<"Coming here"<<std::endl;
        throw obj;
    }
    catch(Box msg){
        std::cout<<"I have caught the exception: \n"<<msg.show()<<std::endl;
    }    
}
```

and result will be:

```
Coming here
copy                          // <-- for throw
Box destructor is executed
copy                          // <-- when you catch at catch(Box msg)
Box show executed
I have caught the exception: 
msg
Box destructor is executed
Box destructor is executed
```

What are these `copy`'s are for? one is for `throw obj;` and other is for `catch(Box msg)`.

Comment: "Because it wants to evaluate show() method in catch section, it will print string first." this doesn't make any sense. Could you elaborate?

Comment: it doesn't make sense at all: repl.it/repls/SpiffyElaborateAnalysis

Comment: @niceboy-programmer `copy`'s are completely logical. as I updated my answer one copy if for when you use `throw obj` and another copy is when you catch it at `catch(Box msg)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help you to follow what is going on if you add the constructor and copy constructor to your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Box {
public:
    std::string show() {
        std::cout << "Box show executed - " << this << std::endl;
        return "msg";
    };

    Box() {
        std::cout << "Box constructor is executed " << this << std::endl;
    }

    Box(const Box& rhs) {
        std::cout << "Box copy constructor is executed " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~Box() {
        std::cout << "Box destructor is executed " << this << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {

    try {
        Box obj;
        std::cout << "Coming here" << std::endl;
        throw obj;
    }
    catch (Box msg) {
        std::cout << "I have caught the exception: \n" << msg.show() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

This produces the following output:

```
/*
Box constructor is executed 0051FB0B 
Coming here 
Box copy constructor is executed 0051FA33
Box copy constructor is executed 0051FAFF 
Box destructor is executed 0051FB0B 
Box show executed - 0051FAFF 
I have caught the exception: msg 
Box destructor is executed 0051FAFF 
Box destructor is executed 0051FA33
*/
```

So you can see the answer to #1 is that two new objects are getting created during the throw and catch. Immediately after that, the original object is destructed because it is now out of its block scope.

The next part is a little confusing because there are two nested std::cout statements. In this case, the compiler chose to fully resolve the expression msg.show() before it produced the output for the first part of the line "I have caught the exception...". So as it was resolving the value for msg.show(), msg.show() first produced its own output line "Box show ....." which is why it came first. As S.M. pointed out in his answer, the order in which the compiler chooses to evaluate the nested std::cout is implementation defined and this order of operations is not guaranteed.

Lastly, the object created in the catch is destructed and then the object created from the try is destructed.